# could not retrieve more than 30 workflow run details from Azure logic App Monitoring Rest Api

Tags: winforms, azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-management-api

Iam creating one monitoring tool in C# winforms to get workflow run details(Success and failure count of runs) of Logic App.
 When iam using the below API call in httpclient i could get only 30 workflow run details.

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/{workflowName}/runs?api-version=2016-06-01
```

using postman tool also retrieves the same data.

Could you please let us know how to get all the run details for the specific workflow

Comment: If my reply is helpful, you could accept it as the answer, thanks.

Comment: you can enable log analytics and get the same stuff as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could not list all the data via this rest api, if it is acceptable, you could pass the `$top` parameter(it has a `PageSizeLimit` of `250`), the parameter decides the number of items to be included in the result. E.g `50`, then it will return `50` items in the result.

More details see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/logic/workflowruns/list#uri-parameters),

[image]

Sample:

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/{workflowName}/runs?api-version=2016-06-01&$top=50
```